# What is the opposite of "to reminisce"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure "opposite" is the correct word, but I am searching for a word that is about remembering something unpleasant.

When I searched the Internet for an opposte of "to reminisce", I only found words about not remembering, and not about remembering something unpleasant.

Comment: _Reminisce_ doesn't necessarily have a good connotation; it's just that it's volitional -- i.e, one does it on purpose -- and generally one only does this for pleasant memories. Reminiscing about when one's fingernails were pulled out is not a likely activity.

Comment: The best I can think of is something pretty neutral such as _to recollect_. Most words for what you're looking for aren't verbs but nouns (like _flashback_ suggested below).

Comment: I think "brood on" is probably fairly close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ruminate**

> **Rumination (psychology)**
>
> Rumination is the compulsively focused attention on the symptoms of
> one's distress, and on its possible causes and consequences, as
> opposed to its solutions. Rumination is similar to worry except
> rumination focuses on bad feelings and experiences from the past,
> whereas worry is concerned with potential bad events in the future.
> Both rumination and worry are associated with anxiety and other
> negative emotional states.
> <sub>[Wikipedia: *Rumination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumination_(psychology))</sub>

#### Is Dwelling on the Negative Hurting You? The Cognitive Costs of Rumination

> You are sitting at home and your mind keeps going over the negatives
> -- over and over. You keep reviewing what has happened to you -- perhaps a conflict with someone, something at work, your living
> conditions, your finances, your health. Whatever. You dwell on it. You
> are stuck.
>
> **What is Rumination?**
>
> A lot of people sit at home, dwell on the negative and find themselves
> getting deeper and deeper in their depression. Psychologists call this
> style of repetitive negative thoughts "rumination." When cows
> ruminate, they chew on their cud, chomping over and over without
> swallowing. When humans ruminate, they repeat negative thoughts over
> and over, dwelling on something either in the past or the present --
> but do nothing to change anything. Ruminating is like spinning your
> wheels in the mud. You don't seem to be getting anywhere, so you just
> keep spinning your wheels, faster and faster. You keep digging a hole,
> find yourself stuck, and dig deeper and deeper.
>
> Examples of rumination include repeating in your mind negative
> experiences in the past, replaying conversations that you had,
> dwelling on the "injuries" and "injustices" that you have suffered, or
> asking questions that don't have answers, such as "Why am I so
> depressed?," "Why me?," "What is the meaning of all of this?" or "Why
> did he or she say that?" You may ruminate about your physical
> maladies, your aches and pains, your emotions, your sensations or just
> about anything. The key thing is that you are stuck.
> <sub>[Huffington Post: *Is Dwelling on the Negative Hurting You? by Robert Leahy, Ph.D.*](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/robert-leahy-phd/dwelling-on-the-negative-_b_799103.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Would *flashback* be the word? It's maybe not specific enough, but certainly in connection with, say *acid flashback* it has unpleasant connotations.

> **flashback** *noun*
>   1.1 A disturbing sudden vivid memory of an event in the past, typically as the result of psychological trauma or taking LSD.
>   ‘The drinking continued during his disembarkation leave; and he says that by that stage he was experiencing numerous flashbacks to the traumatic events that he had witnessed.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flashback)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Stuart. Your answer would be more valuable if you cited a dictionary of other authoritative resource.

Comment: Thank you, ScotM - is that the expected procedure/format here? Sorry, I am very new!

Comment: [Yes](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) :-)

Comment: @ScotM Where does it say that? I don't see it in http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Barmar: "*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*"

Comment: @ScotM That's saying that you shouldn't post link-only answers, you should include the relevant material here in addition to the link. It's not saying that answers without links are bad.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, @Barmar: I agree that Stuart's answer is a **good** start. An answer with an authoritative citation would be ***more valuable***. That seems to be consistent with the straightforward proposition: "Links to external resources are encouraged." . The preponderance of high quality answers contain a combination of fresh insight, authoritative citations **and** links, and it seems wise to encourage new users in that direction from the beginning.

Comment: I've added a dictionary entry for you. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll it back if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get something unpleasant out of your head, you would **agonize** over it.

> [agonize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agonize) (verb) - to think or worry very much about something; to cause to suffer agony

Answer (score 1):

> **dwell on/upon**
>
> *verb (past and past participle dwelt or dwelled)*
>
> 2 (dwell on/upon) Think, speak, or write at length about (a particular
>   subject, especially one that is a source of unhappiness, anxiety, or
>   dissatisfaction):
>   *I’ve got better things to do than **dwell on** the past*
> <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dwell)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would add "lament" to this list as it deals with mourning and grief.

A lament or lamentation is a passionate expression of grief, often in music, poetry, or song form. The grief is most often born of regret, or mourning. Laments can also be expressed in a verbal manner, where the participant would lament about something they regret or someone they've lost, usually accompanied by wailing, moaning and/or crying. Laments constitute some of the oldest forms of writing and examples are present across human cultures.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with off the top of my head is to re-experience and the description of the experience  would clarify the negative connotation.

Example:  "My father smalled the rain and began to scan the sky, it was as if he were re-experiencing the jungles of Viet Nam."

Source:[Re-experiencing symptoms are a specific cluster of PTSD symptoms](http://ptsd.about.com/od/glossary/g/Reexperiencedef.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To dwell on something means to keep one's self on the past,  not to think about the past periodically,  while to ruminate is as good as bringing the past to present through thoughts.  I'll put it as: "she keeps dwelling and ruminating the traumatic experience of her time with her first husband". 
Hope this works..